# importing a text file in python

Tags: python, file, import

I am very new to python. I just want to know where will we import the file, we want to run a script on, in the following python script. I just want to import or refer to a file in the script below

```
import fileinput, optparse

usage = """%prog HOCOMOCOv9_AD_TRANSFAC.txt > converted_transfac_matrices.txt

 This program reads matrices in a format used by the TRANSFAC database,
 and writes them in a format that can be used by Clover.  The TRANSFAC
 format looks something like this:

 AC  M00002
 XX
 P0      A      C      G      T
 01      4      4      3      0      V
 02      2      5      4      0      S
 03      3      2      4      2      N"""


op = optparse.OptionParser(usage=usage)
(opts, args) = op.parse_args()
if not args: op.error("please specify an input file")

title = []

for line in fileinput.input(args):
    w = line.split()
    key = w[0]
    if key in ("AC", "ID", "NA"):
        title.extend(w[1:])
    elif key.isdigit():
        if title:
            print ">" + " ".join(title)
            title = []
        print "\t".join(w[1:5])
```

Comment: I'm confused - exactly **what** do you want to do?

Comment: I just can't find a way to import my text file in the script above. I want to run this script on a text file. I don't know how to refer to or import that particular text file. This is the first time in am doing python

Comment: You mean you want to *read* a text file?

Comment: Yes I want to pass the text file in the above script or read it. YES

Comment: Just call your script with the file as parameter: `python YOUR_SCRIPT.py YOUR_INPUT_FILE`

Comment: I mean where do I refer to my file or import my file in the above script. I am sorry. I know these are basic questions but I don't have a clue. How to read in my file

Comment: [optparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/optparse.html). You might want to consider [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) instead.

Comment: There is no script above. You removed it in your last edit after undeleting.

Comment: Stop trying to blank your question. It's already indexed by search engines, and future readers will be very confused when the search engine shows them a snippet of code or description and they follow the link to find none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This?

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f_open:
    data = f_open.read()

print data
```

or

```
f_open = open('file.txt','r')
data = f_open.read()
f_open.close()

print data
```

or

```
python script.py
```

or

```
python script.py text.txt
```

or

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as open_csv:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(open_csv)

print csv_reader
```

Someone unclear post :S